# How to clean csv data over multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, data-cleaning

I'm trying to help a non profit with some data analysis. Their spreadsheets look like this:

[image]

The 'S1' stand for sensor and there are two readings (temp & Humidity), which are taken three times a day (6 12 6). How do I make columns to get data for 'S1', like daily avg, weekly, avg, monthly avg for both temp and humidity? I might be in over my head on this one. I can use pandas for basic stuff but I can't figure out how to combine columns under one heading of 'S1'?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

This is as far as i've got. Not sure I'm on the right path or not?

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataframe is not so bad after all. You have only one exception on lines (2, 3) vs 7, 11, 15, etc. Another minor problem is for hours: I assume hours are 6AM, 12PM and 6PM, so they need to be converted as 6, 12 and 18 in 24-Hour time format. If my assumptions are right and your screenshot contains no more exception, you can clean your data like this:

```
# Read data file without header/index and don't let pandas infers the dtype
df = pd.read_csv('TestData.csv', header=None, dtype=str)
m = df[1].notna() & df[0].isna()

# Create datetime index (rows)
dt = (pd.to_datetime(df[0].ffill() + ' ' + df[1], format='%d-%b-%y %H')
        .rename('DateTime')[m])
dt[2::3] += pd.DateOffset(hours=12)  # convert 6PM to 18

# Create multi-index headers (columns)
cols = df.loc[[0, 1]].ffill(axis=1).dropna(how='all', axis=1).T
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(cols, names=['Sensor', 'Metric'])

# Final output (remove two first columns)
out = df.loc[m, 2:].set_axis(dt, axis=0).set_axis(mi, axis=1).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
Sensor                 S1          S2          S3      
Metric                  T     %     T     %     T     %
DateTime                                               
2023-08-01 06:00:00  30.3  87.0  29.4  86.0  29.5  65.0
2023-08-01 12:00:00  30.4  89.0  29.4  87.0  29.4  69.0
2023-08-01 18:00:00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2023-08-02 06:00:00  29.7  93.0  29.0  88.0  28.5  70.0
2023-08-02 12:00:00  29.5  93.0  28.8  88.0  28.4  70.0
2023-08-02 18:00:00  31.7  93.0  30.3  88.0  30.3  69.0
...

>>> out.index
DatetimeIndex(['2023-08-01 06:00:00', '2023-08-01 12:00:00',
               '2023-08-01 18:00:00', '2023-08-02 06:00:00',
               '2023-08-02 12:00:00', '2023-08-02 18:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DateTime', freq=None)

>>> out.columns
MultiIndex([('S1', 'T'),
            ('S1', '%'),
            ('S2', 'T'),
            ('S2', '%'),
            ('S3', 'T'),
            ('S3', '%')],
           names=['Sensor', 'Metric'])
```

**Note**: To correctly convert date, your locale must be English. As my locale is French, I have to switch to English like this:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'en_US.utf8')  # or 'C'
# 'en_US.utf8' is probably only valid on Linux and OSX, not Windows
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your time!! Everything works except for the last line of code and I get the following error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'T'

Comment: Remove `.astype(float)` and check the output. Maybe you have misaligned rows. Can you share the file?

Comment: Here is the link to one of the files: 
  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kYosUHymrSLkdEmLDW-aOIWeRdD2aa5l/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: For 18, 19, 21 and 22 august, you have a 8 in the hour column.

Comment: I updated my answer. I just changed the boolean mask `m` to make it more robust. It works with your test data file ;-)

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to do calculations on it?  TypeError: Could not convert ['30.330.429.729.5' '87899393'] to numeric

Comment: Your data is not that clean :-( Try `out = pd.to_numeric(df.loc[m, 2:].set_axis(dt, axis=0).set_axis(mi, axis=1), errors='coerce')

Comment: I got it now!! Thank you!!!